# Swipe event between two UITableViews with animation

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview

I've been building an IOS app in wich I have two UITableViews in one ViewController.

I implemented a simple event that the user swipes up the content a UITableViewCell from one UITableView to another. It captures the "swipe up" event and updates the both NSMutableArrays binded to the Table Views.

The problem is that this event is kind of "flat", as it doesn't show the cell's content merging from one table to another. It simply delete from one UITableView and move the cell content to the other UITableView.

I'd like to put some visual effects, for the user really feels that he/she is in fact moving the content.

Any ideas?

Comment: You might resize the uiview in table A cell(collapse it) and move it to table  B cell. Then expend table B cell.
Or to be simple, fade out the view in A and move a small icon to table B and create view in table B.

Comment: @Horst It's definitely a better approach than mine, but I was thinking about when you drag a file in your computer with the mouse and sees the content following the cursor.

Comment: http://www.scott-sherwood.com/tutorial/ios-5-drag-and-drop-between-uitableviews/
This tutorial sounds fit for your case(never tried it.)